# Is this real image of Kaanchi Kamakshi?

Tags: temple, identification-request, devi

I just want to know if this is the real image of Kanchi Kamakshi or an image of goddess from some other temple. Anyone who visited the temple please answer me. I am thinking this is not a real image as there is no srichakra as told in front of kamakshi. So if it was the real pic then please answer me where is the sri chakra placed in the temple? Is it placed outside the garbalaya of Kamakshi?

[image: a pic found in the google]

Comment: It doesn't seem real to me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is just an excellent painting, very convincing and close to the actual idol too. I had an opportunity to sit inside the gayatri mantapa for 15 minutes, as I had paid for a special pooja. The garland is a giveaway in this photo. Also other aspects - the facial features are slightly different. The actual idol is not so well polished with such clean finish unlike many modern sculptures. Also the idol has higher cheeks. The sanctum sanctorum is definitely not so well lit as there are no electric lights. There are also a couple of hanging lamps on either sides partially visible, but let's ignore that for now since they can be removed anytime. The door is also not this wide. You can't really see any gaps on the sides. Especially from the distance at which this photo seems to be taken. In fact the idol of 'tapa kamakshi' which is right next to the main idol is missing in this photo. In reality that idol is also not visible from far unless you are sitting closer to the sanctum in the gayatri mantapa. The hollow which is right in front of the sanctum sanctorum's threshold is also missing in this photo. It is right in front of the threshold and it is only by carefully lifting the feet along the sides, the priests enter the sanctum sanctorum. The hollow is mistaken by many for srichakra. But it just is a dent in the ground that symbolizes navel (of sati since it is a shaktipeeta). The hollow is filled with flowers most of the time, in fact the idol is just symbolic and the actual deity is believed to reside in the hollow. This is believed to be the opening in the ground from where the goddess appeared in order to kill bhandasura (some local legends only). May be a gold/brass srichakra is placed in that hollow, hence leading to this misconception.

In fact this idol was consecrated by Adi Shankaracharya when he established kamakoti peeta. Before that the Adi kamakshi idol which is now located in the adjacent street was considered as moola kamakshi. There the deity is depicted as holding a kapaala (vessel to drink blood/wine). Adi Shankaracharya gave a calmer representation for the deity with a depiction of sugarcane and flower arrows. He reconsecrated kamakshi in this new temple.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

If you closely look to the image you shared and this image, you will find that the ornaments are not exactly same.

[image]

Yet another proof that, these are from Kanchipuram. You can see Maha Periyava (Kanchi Shankaracharya) standing near it. Now, no one can question it's authenticity .

```
So if it was the real pic then please answer me where is the sri chakra placed in the temple? Is it placed outside the garbalaya of Kamakshi?
```

As, @essenceofdharma said the Nabhi is situated out the threshold of Grabhagriha. And its missing in the image you shared.

You can see it here,

[image]

Yet, another image of Kamakshi, I dont know even if this is real.

But the image you shared looks just like a miniature art, created by some artist.

[image]

If you give a closer look, the garland is cloured by acrylic thus the surface looks so shiny. Or in case of real flowers they would never shine.
There are some more facts like,
There are no side lamps at doorstep.       Since, at Kamakshi's threshold on both sides are two lamps placed at daily hours. Thus logically speaking when photos must have been clicked, they should still be there.
Her hands apparently have no finishing.
Her ornaments too looks like a foil is been sticked.
But, the biggest point here is, there is a bit more gap between Kamakshi at Kanchipuram and the doors. Whereas here the devi is just so close and thus hardly any space left to move inside the Garbhagriha.
Thus, all this put together gives me an artistic appearance.

This can be proved further with one more picture,

[image]

If you see the artist have tagged herself. And this is the replica she made of Kamakshi Ambal. To normal eyes it would look as real Garbhagriha as she have gave such a finishing, but it's not.

Thus concluding, that, this doesn't appears as real Kanchi Kamakshi's vigraha to me.

[image]

Her abhushans out on streets to bless everyone with their glance.

Her Abhushans too are so beautiful, truly She is called **Tri-Pura Sundari** ❤️.

**कलिकार्पणमस्तु ।**